# Modifying one end of a spiral/curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves, edit-mode

I have created a spiral using the "Add curve" function and want to taper just one end of it (kind of like extruding and narrowing). Is there a way to do this? If not, what would be the best way create a spiral that enables the modification of its ends. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You may do it using a *curve* as a ***Taper Object's*** target to change the thickness along the spiral's axis. You can then change its width using the curve's *specials* menu.
[image]

After creating a *curve* add a *Bezier Circle* and set it as a target in the *Bevel Object* window (*Curve Data* header).
[image]

Add a *Bezier Curve* and edit it in *Edit Mode* so it's straight and placed vertical.
[image]

Select the *spiral* in *Object Mode* and set the newly added *Bezier Curve* as a ***Taper Object*** target.
[image]

Modify the newly added *curve* to change the thickness along the *spiral*'s axis. Experiment with it for different results.
[image]
[image]

Finally select the *spiral* in *Object Mode*, press <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Width Size* and drag the cursor away to change its width.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Every curve point has a radius value that will adjust the bevel radius and can be found in the properties region.

[image: curve point tranform properties]

You can use <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to adjust the radius value and combined with proportional editing you can get a gradual falloff from the active point.