# Screw shape with Curve

Tags: bezier-curves, screw-modifier

How can I get a curve on screw shape/line ? Is it possible in Blender ? I made the mesh above in the picture by screwing an hexagon (circle with 6 edges).

But this way, it is hard to work on its edges without deforming it.
So far result:

[image]

My aim is to make like metal part in picture below. So it would be easier with curve modifier.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/how-can-i-create-twisted-geometry also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80420/create-spiral-out-of-circle

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79520/modifying-one-end-of-a-spiral-curve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding bevel and taper to the spiral curve like this (of course smooth shading and subsurf will help).

starting with a setup like this:

[image]

you can get something like that shape using bevel, bevel object and taper to the shown curve circle:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve it using ***Extra Objects (Curve)*** add on, then *beveling* a *curve* and edit it with a *proportional editing*.
[image]

Activate the add on in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

Go to *Add*-->*Curve*-->*Spirals*.
[image]

Play with a spiral's settings in a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

When you're done keep extruding the bottom segments of a curve to create vertical part of a corkscrew. Add a *Bezier Circle* and use it for beveling the curve.
[image]

Finally enable the *proportional editing*, select the very end segment of a spiral, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to adjust its bevel radius. Use <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd> to adjust the influence of *proportional editing*. To make the end of the spiral sharp select the last curve's segment and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explanation. I was just not so familiar with  spiral curves as i am new on Blender. Also i wanted curve go down with not decrasing radius and i figured it was logarithmic curve sprials. :)